# Image saved in database cannot be updated

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, image, linq

I have been googling for a solution to my problem for two days without any luck. Can any stars in MVC3 .NET help?

I am trying to build an .NET MVC3 application to update images saved in an database.

Here is the action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(myImage img, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        //var img = (from imga in db.myImages
        //              where imga.imageID == id
        //            select imga).First();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (img != null)
            {
                img.imageType = imageFile.ContentType;
                img.Data  = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];
                imageFile.InputStream.Read(img.Data, 0, imageFile.ContentLength);
            }
            // save the product
            UpdateModel(img);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            // there is something wrong with the data values
            return View(img);
        }
    }
```

Here is the view

```
@model JackLing.Models.myImage

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>Edit</h2>

   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Image",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       <fieldset>
           <legend>myImage</legend>
           @Html.EditorForModel();

           <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
           <div class="editor-field">
           @if (Model.Data != null)
           {
            <img src="@Url.Action("show", new { id = Model.imageID })" height="150" width="150" />
           }
           else { 
           @:None
           }
           </div>

           <p>
              <span>Choose a new file</span> <input type="file" name="imgFile"/>
           </p>

           <p>
               <input type="submit" value="Save" />
           </p>

       </fieldset>
   }

   <div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
   </div>
```

When I run the application it throws an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any suggestions on how to fix the problems will be appriciated! By the way, the create and details method are all working. I think it has to do with data binding, but I'm not sure... I have no clue how to fix it.

---

Finally fixed the problem based on the advice from Eulerfx
here is the working action.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(myImage img, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
        {
            myImage imgToSave = (from imga in db.myImages
                          where imga.imageID == img.imageID
                         select imga).First();



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (img != null)
                {
                    imgToSave.imageType = imageFile.ContentType;
                    var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(imageFile.InputStream);
                    imgToSave.Data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(imageFile.ContentLength);
                    binaryReader.Close();
                }


                TryUpdateModel(imgToSave);

                db.SubmitChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                // there is something wrong with the data values
                return View(img);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show your GET action?

Comment: And which line of code is throwing the "Object reference" error?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! here is the get action  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            
            myImage mi = (from img in db.myImages
                          where img.imageID == id
                          select img).First();
            return View(mi);
        }

Comment: img.imageType = imageFile.ContentType;
this line is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the name of the file input field in the HTML is imgeFile and the name of the file parameter in MVC is imageFile. Ensure that the input field name and the action method parameter names match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and let know the result soon! Chero!

Comment: the error is indeed caused by the input field name. changed to imageFile and the error message went away. But the image still stay unupdated...maybe only one step away from the final solution. any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance! Is MVC3 making things harder or easier?

Comment: It looks like you aren't loading a database entity to be updated, instead myImage img is a binding parameter which would explain why nothing is saved.

Comment: Hi eulerfx, i wrote db.SubmitChanges();in the code. isnt this line supposed to load the database? I create an instance of my database at the controller level. Do i have to redo it in my action? Please kindly advice the correct code. Many yhanks!

Comment: By the way i am using ling for data access

Comment: The call to db.SubmitChanges() will only persist changes made to an object to the database when than object was originally loaded from the DB or an explicit save was called. In your case, it looks like the load call is commented and the object that you wish to persist is created by the MVC binding system and is therefore not managed by the linq2sql.

Comment: Yeah..You are correct Eulerfx!! Finally got it right based on your advice. You are a champion! How can I give your a five star vote? I am very new to here.